# Fill GridView in Fragment with Data

Tags: java, android, gridview, fragment

I am trying to fill a GridView with some Data in Fragment.
If I start my application, it only show you a blank white screen. No data.
I used a CustomAdapter with an extra class.

I cannot find it, so I would be happy if anyone here can help me.
If you need any other code, please tell me!

> CustomAdapter

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `public int getCount() { return 0; }` - You need to return `output.size()` there.

Comment: You need `return output.size();`, specifically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
public int getCount() { return 0; }
```

With:

```
public int getCount() { return output.size(); }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return output.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return output[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
@Override
    public void onResponse(String string) {
        getActivity().parseJsonData(string);
    }
```

Comment: maye you could explain better how this code solves the problem mentioned by the OP